# PHP HTML to DOC

Tags: php, html, converters, doc

I'm using the following to convert a html file to doc.

The following example works great and it does exactly what it should, but I have another document, but in this document I use mainly `<div>`s and not tables.
It seems that the conversion or `fooling` of word does not work when using `div`s.

Am I right? The content of the document comes through, but the layout and style is completely shot to pieces.

Running the `div` doc as a normal html file look perfect.

any ideas please.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='DischargeLetter.doc'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

$text = "$text="<style type='text/css'>
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-uhkr{background-color:#ffce93}
.tg .tg-wsnc{background-color:#fffc9e}
.tg .tg-glis{font-size:10px}
.tg .tg-7khl{font-size:15px}
.tg .tg-3sk9{font-weight:bold;font-size:12px}
.tg .tg-jzyw{font-weight:bold;font-size:13px}
</style>
<table class='tg'>
  <tr>
    <th class='tg-uhkr' colspan='3'>Logo<br>thaaf<br>la;sdkhf;ls<br>a;slkdhals</th>
    <th class='tg-uhkr' colspan='3''>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='tg-3sk9'>1st Col</td>
    <td class='tg-glis'>2nd col</td>
    <td class='tg-glis'>3rd col</td>
    <td class='tg-jzyw'>4th col</td>
    <td class='tg-glis'>5th col</td>
    <td class='tg-glis'>6th col</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='tg-wsnc' colspan='6'>Row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='tg-7khl' colspan='2'>1 of 3</td>
    <td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>2 of 3</td>
    <td class='tg-031e' colspan='2'>3 of 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>";




echo $text;
```

Comment: So exactly what bit of code here converts html to doc format? Looks like all you're doing is generating a few extra styles for html and pretending that it magically converts it to word format

Comment: you're not printing to word. you're generating an html document and word is politely PRETENDING it's a word file for you. word's html rendering engine has always been crap. you shouldn't be doing this and expecting to get the same results you do in a browser.

Comment: @MarkBaker. I know its not a conversion, but merely a fooling process, but my point is that it works for html tables, but not for htam div's. And I was wondering if this "fooling" is this primitive to only understand html tables

Comment: Okay, I have the complete html file that looks and works perfect. How do I convert that into a doc, rtf. Ive done pdf's before, but I need it to be editable, hence the doc conversion.

Comment: @morne: Were you able to find a suitable solution to your problem? I have the same issue and any help you can give me would be great :)

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar - no quite, I settled by saving it as PDF. I placed a "save/print" button on the page. This calls the print functionality and then you can choose to print or save it with "PDFCreator". This is SO much easier the taking the Doc path.